# White ring on MacBook Air's screen

Tags: macbook-pro, screen, damage

There is a problem with the screen of my MacBook Air (13", Early 2015). A white ring-shape water-mark appears on the screen, which is similar to the luminous Apple in size. The ring is particularly obvious in white background. This has actually happened before and the screen was replaced three time (under AppleCare). Still the problem seems to appear gradually, around one month after replacement.

Last time, the staff at Genius Bar told me that it *might* be caused by excessive pressure, but pressure really can't make such kind of damage in a short period of time (and he admitted that the cause of damage was unknown). Now the problem reappears, and since it is very inconvenient if I have to visit an Apple Store every month, I would like to ask the following:

1. Is there any other possible cause of such kind of screen damage?
2. If so, how to prevent repeated damage?
3. Should I (or would it be possible to) ask for a refurbished machine
   instead of just replacing the screen? (And would it be better?)
4. How is it likely that the problem appears again if I am going to ask
   for another repair?

I usually carry my MacBook Air with a soft laptop bag (which was suggested by a technician in the Genius Bar when I had my second repair). Not sure if it helps, though.

Comment: Please add a pic - probably best is to turn off the Mac, position a light source  with a 20°- 45° angle and take a shot from the opposite side (also with an angle). Also: white watermark best seen on white background? Doesn't seem very plausible...

Comment: Em..yes, the white watermark is best seen on white background. It doesn't appear when the screen is off. The watermark is too dim to be seen in a photo...it gets worse soon though...

Comment: @tony200910041 In situations where a photo can't capture something like this, I always take a short video instead. Perhaps you could do that and then upload it somewhere we can view it from? Otherwise it's a bit hard to _get_ a clear idea of what's happening.